# Which functional group is -CSSH?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, organosulfur-compounds

If we replace two oxygen in $\ce{-COOH}$ what is the name of the compound we get?

Comment: Does that functional group even exist? If so, do you have an example of a molecule containing it?

Comment: Yes the compound exists, it is formed when grignard reagent reacts with thioxide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is a dithioic acid.

For example, a benzene with two -CSSH hubstituents in 1, 2 positions is a benzene-1,2-dicarbodithioic acid.

Comment: Here's a [neat reference](http://books.google.com/books?id=cAm7rA_D25wC&lpg=PA550&ots=GZbk5Yl1t9&pg=PA545#v=onepage&q&f=false) containing all sorts of information about carboxylic acid analogues contaning heavier chalcogens.

Comment: isn't it just a thioic acid? that thio there means sulfur so why is it a dithioic acid instead of just thioic acid?

Comment: @Caters, likely because '-thioic acid' would imply replacement of only one of the oxygens with a sulfur, instead of both.